# Google Chrome is unable to apply opacity transition on a 3d transformed element

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="cube trigger cuberotate">
    <div class="face init f z"></div>
    <div class="face init l y"></div>
    <div class="face init b z"></div>
    <div class="face init r y"></div>
    <div class="face init u x"></div>
    <div class="face init d x"></div>
</div>
```

Which resembles a 3d cube, every face is rotated and translated onto their proper position and I let the cube rotate using an animation on the faces' parent.

Here's the related css of it:

```
.cube {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;

  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;

  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;

  border: 0px solid #fff;
  background: #c82222;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0px;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  user-select: none;

  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;    
}
```

I wanted to make the cube appear one face at time on document ready, so I just threw in some javascript, basically an interval every 500ms which simply removes the `.init` class which overrides the `opacity: 1` value on the `.face` class.

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  // Some selectors and shit...
  var $face = $('.face').first(),
      speed = 500,
      timer = null;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Start showing faces
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
      var $next = $face.next();

      $face.removeClass('init');

      if(!$next.hasClass('face')) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
      }

      $face = $next;
    }, speed);

  });


})(jQuery);


// And the additional CSS below
.face.init {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

In an ideal world this code should work, however I am facing a problem on Google Chrome the opacity doesn't transition back to 1 after the class is removed keeping the cube completely invisible. If you right click and inspect it becomes visible again.

Curiously on Safari, which is also a webkit-based browser this does not happen at all and the faces show one at time as they are supposed to do.

I tried to use both `.animate()` from jquery and also tried the jquery plugin [transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

- Now, Safari and Chrome aren't supposed to behave in the same way, or are there major differences under the hood despite the rendering engine being the same?
- Is it something I did wrong?
- There's a workaround for this?

Here's my pen:
http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/FstKG/

Thanks

**Update:**

I have tried obviously on Chrome on my Mac and also on Windows 7 and they both behave the same way (different machines also)

Also tried Firefox which works seamlessly like Safari apart from the rotating animation which isn't happening (but I kept Firefox out of consideration as it's a different browser).

**Additional update:**

Chrome on mobile devices (both iOS and Android) are working and behaving like Safari on desktop.

**Another Update:**

After playing around around I have found probably it's a browser bug, Chrome Canary works fine as expected.
I posted this on facebook where I've got a couple of good workarounds from a developer, which I found quite creative.

The first one involved in have a rgba() background-color and make the alpha change instead of having the transition on the opacity: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IjsBL

The second one involved a bit of javascript coding, forcing the browser repaint the faces at each frame: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hofzb

I am starting a bounty to see what stackoverflow can do here!

Comment: It would be nice to post those workaround for other users facing this problem (*although the bug is fixed in canary and should be incorporated in stable in the near future*)

Comment: I'm the developer who provided the workarounds on Facebook. I'll write an answer with them now. Although the `opacity: 0.01;` hurts me a little :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to assign 0.01 to `opacity`.

```
.face.init {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Comment: This is completely flattening, I should've be ashamed of not thinking about this

Comment: I am accepting this as correct answer as it's the easiest way to solve this problem. In addition to that I am quitting web development.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is a [documented regression bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346237&q=css%20transform%20opacity&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

For the difference in Safari and Chrome, you should know that Chrome uses [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink)(*a webkit fork*) as its rendering engine since version 28.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was brought to my attention on Facebook. As requested, I'll post my initial thought process.

#### Initial Thought: Aggressive GPU-use / hardware-acceleration

Initially, I thought Chrome was seeing the 3D transforms in the keyframes-animation and hardware accelerating the animation -- which is what we expect -- but then when trying to interfere via JavaScript, was not interrupting the GPU execution.

#### Workaround 1:

Use a separate keyframes-animation first to animate opacity and rotation at the same time and then start your current animation, animating just the rotation to continue infinitely.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Egboi).

#### Workaround 2:

I then immediately realised he wanted each face to fade in independently, in sequence. Knowing javascript wasn't interrupting the CSS animation, I tried animating the `.face`s using a keyframes-animation. Using an `animation-delay` to stagger each face.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wstEJ). But for some reason, it stops after the first face :(

#### Workaround 3:

At this point I was clutching at straws, and thought to toggle `perspective: 500px` to `perspective: 501px`, within a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, in hopes it would break hardware-acceleration, but no luck.

#### Workaround 3.1:

But having used a `requestAnimationFrame`, I decided I could just perform the first rotation and intended fade-in's using javascript and then trigger the CSS animation after.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hofzb). This was the intended visual.

#### Workaround 4:

While anyone else would have been done and dusted, still using javascript bugged me to hell -- as much as I love JS, CSS is just smoother (right now).

Then it hit me! I could just animate `background-color: rgba(...);` rather than `opacity: ...;`.

And so finially, I had the intended animation using pure CSS.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IjsBL).

This was based on **Workaround 2**. I had to create 3 extra animations: one for each colour `.face` identified with classes `.x`, `.y` and `.z`.

I used SCSS to make it clear I was using the original colours (hence the `rgba(#c82222,0);`) and also to save myself the ball-ache of having to convert that to RGB values anyway.

---

Hope that helps *anyone* :)

Comment: Noticed now the 3.1 you posted stops working if the tab loses focus or if it doesn't have focus at all. For example, if you CTRL+click to open in the new tab and then switch on that after the page it's loaded looks like it's stuck at the start.

Comment: Yeah. The `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks won't get called while the window/tab isn't focused/active. Could fix that by applying the `opacity: 1` to the `.face`s in the `time >= duration` branch. Or handling the `window.onblur`/`window.onfocus` events to pause/unpause the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to initiate opacity from zero with bit more transition values.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't totally understood what you meant. Can you expand your answer by making an example?

Answer (score 0):

CSS position relative fixes the problem:

```
.fullscreen {
  position: relative;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oekyt

It reminds me the of old IE bugs then you have to set

```
*zoom: 1;
```

for element. It made element "really rendered", not just "light rendered".

Comment: Apparently this solution doesn't work either, it behaves like the original one I've posted.